# List to gwt ListStore collector

Tags: java, gwt, java-stream, collectors

I need to convert the objects list to ListStore. I can do it with forEach. But I want to do it with stream API. Are there some collectors to collect collection to GWT ListStore or it is required to write own collector?
My current implementation:

```
private ListStore<ComboBoxItemModel<SomeObject>> someObjectsToComboBoxListStore(List<SomeObject> someObjects) {
        ListStore<ComboBoxItemModel<SomeObject>> list = new ListStore<>();
        for (SomeObject someObject : someObjects) {
            list.add(new ComboBoxItemModel<>(someObject));
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of stream API you looking for is called map. Map is same as

1. iterate over stream of objects
2. return a new stream of mapped objects

In this particular example it would look something like this:

```
        someObjects.stream().map(someObject -> new ComboBoxItemModel(someObject.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This blog helped me a lot, it will teach you among other things, how to write custom collectors, which can be useful very often.

https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/stream-map-example/

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I asked. I know how to use .map. I need at the end to collect mapped objects. Collectors.toList() it is the collector for List, but I need it for ListStore. Something like ListStoreCollectors.toListStore. But I guess it is necessary to write own collector, which is quite a difficult task

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can add the whole list to ListStore. So I can map my objects to what I need and add them all to ListStore:

```
ListStore<ComboBoxItemModel<SomeObject>> listStore = new ListStore<>();
        listStore.add(someObjects.stream()
            .map(object -> new ComboBoxItemModel<>(object))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return listStore;
```

Looks even more complicated than with forEach

Answer (score 0):

Using `Stream.reduce` works well if a `ListStore` can
only `add` one item at a time:

```
private ListStore<ComboBoxItemModel<SomeObject>> someObjectsToComboBoxListStore(
        List<SomeObject> someObjects) {
    ListStore<ComboBoxItemModel<SomeObject>> listStore = new ListStore<>();
    someObjects.stream().reduce(
            listStore, (listStore, object) -> listStore.add(
                    new ComboBoxItemModel<>(object)));
    return listStore;
}
```